# Sass::SyntaxError: Colors must have either three or six digits: '#b'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am getting the following error just after upgrading to rails 4.2.0. It used to work fine and I didn't even touch that file, so I am not quite sure what makes the sass gem raise this error. My `gemfile` ->

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.4'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'

# Assets gems
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0'
end
```

And my error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Colors must have either three or six digits: '#b'
  (in /home/travis/build/Vlad-Balanescu/extreme-blue/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):77
```

Comment: Please post your `application.css`. It looks like you've defined a color called `#b`. If you replace it with a valid color, you should be fine.

Comment: It's the `bootstrap.min` file which is raising that issue. I don't have line 77 in `application.css`. And I don't wanna touch that file, it used to work just fine before upgrading to this new version of rails

Comment: Thats strange. But the error message is clear on what's wrong. Are you using a gem to load bootstrap?

Comment: Fixed it. Please see my comment below!. Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had this line:

```
{color:#blue;}
```

under my `bootstrap.min.css` file which wasn't picked up with the previous version of Rails. Odd!